# AngularJS Application Declaration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling to figure out why this particular initialization of my Angular application throws an error.

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'], function AppConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Would appreciate if I could get a hint at what needs to be adjusted here so I can set the `$locationProvider`. Removing the `App.config` part will not throw any errors.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the following: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined`

Comment: Make sure you have the `ng-route` and `angular-ui` script files in your HTML!

Comment: have you added ng-app directive in your Dom element

Comment: Yes I have added all those into my HTML. The errors arises as soon as I add: `App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function AppConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});`

Comment: Removing it still returns the same errors.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing square bracket

Comment: Haha good catch @jpmcc! Now getting this: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=Coachletic&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A180)`

Comment: In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.X or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

Comment: I usually see something like that when I've not included all necessary js files or have a typo in another included file

Comment: I have ng-route as shown in the above code. Currently using 1.4.4.

Comment: Are you actually pulling in the ng-route js file though?

Comment: @jpmcc The strange thing is that this only occurs when I include the following code: `App.config(['$locationProvider'], function ($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});` Without that excluded, the app runs fine which is why I am in a pickle still.

Comment: @jpmcc Yes I am including it: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>`

Comment: Your closing square bracket is in the wrong place. It should be just before the last round bracket, so }]); as your function should be within the array

Comment: @jpmcc Ah there we go! Now onto another error haha `Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$location/nobase`

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux I'd accept that :-)

Comment: Nvm got it https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: @Coachletic For the "nobase" error, try setting the base_path of the app (search google it's easy), it must fix it.

Comment: @Coachletic The doc page you posted shows how to set it using `<base href="/">` in your head.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Is it best practices to include that in the head?

Comment: Nop it's its place. First node inside <head> as recommanded by the W3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `app.config` method, the function callback must be the last array item, after all the dependencies.

Like this:

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Also, the function cannot have a name because it's a callback. Lambda if you prefer.

I had the same problem on my current project.

Note: `app.run` is working the same way.

You may also run into an error with the `$location` looking for a base. This article can be referenced for that: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase